# Printing object array on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working on a Magento 1 maintenance project. On cart page, it is printing quote object array. I am not able to find out from where it is printing. I searched for var_dump and print_r but not able to find out.

Please, any idea how can I debug this?

Like

Array ( [0] => Custom_Sales_Model_Quote_Item Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => sales_quote_item [_eventObject:protected] => item [_quote:protected] => Custom_Sales_Model_Quote Object (

Answer (score 1):

First, you should really be more careful when posting a dump of an object, because this one contains your personal data including email address, the shop url, your password hash, your date of birth etc.

Second, you can also search for `Zend_Debug::dump` or simply `dump(` in `app/code`, `app/design` and `lib/` directories - maybe this helps.

Also check if `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log` contain any related entries.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to turn on template path hints and block names in system > config > developer? You should see the file/function it is coming from.